# Expect and should use the Promise object instead of the resolved result

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

I have the following setup for my unit testing:

```
const mocha = require('mocha')
var chai = require('chai')
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised')
chai.use(chaiAsPromised)

var expect = chai.expect
chai.should()

describe('chain test', function() {
  it('should be a string', function() {
    return Promise.resolve('string').should.to.be.a('string');
  });
});
```

But when I run mocha, then the result is:

```
1) chain test should be a string:  
   AssertionError: expected {} to be a string
```

So it seems as if the test is done against the Promise object itself and not against the resolved result.

According to [chai-as-promised: Installation and Setup](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised#installation-and-setup) the setup is correct.

And the test is created the same way as described in [chai-as-promised: How to Use](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised#how-to-use).

I have tested both the `expect(promise).` and the `promise.should` syntax. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

The used versions of node and the modules are:

- node v4.6.1
- chai 3.5.0
- chai-as-promised 6.0.0
- mocha 3.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake.

The problem is that the correct syntax is not `.should.to.be` but has to be `.should.eventually.be`

Comment: It think that `.to.` can be the problem.